# External file properties not updated - VBA

Tags: vba, file, excel, datecreated

I have a macro that reads out external file properties like date created. The file from where I read is stored on a server. Unfortunately the date returned is not the correct one when running the macro the first time. Only when I open the file or when I run the macro several times, the correct updated date created is returned.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve that issue except from opening the file or looping through until the date is correct?

Here is the code:

```
strFilename = "<FILENAME>"

Workbooks.Open strFilename
Workbooks("strFilename").Close

Set oFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

lastcreatedLTVfile = CDate(Format(oFS.GetFile(strFilename).DateCreated, "dd.mm.yyyy"))
```

Comment: What means "not the correct one"? What exactly is returned?

Comment: `Workbooks("strFilename").Close` should be `Workbooks(strFilename).Close`. I don't see how that solves your issue but needs fixing regardless. Also, why are you taking a date, converting it to a string, and then casting it back to a date again?

Comment: When I open the file and close the file, the date is updated and I can get the right one. But the opening and closing takes time...

Comment: I use a string because the formatting of the date returned is not the one I need, therefore I need to format it first and then convert it into a date again

Answer (score 0):

Do you want `DateCreated` or do you actually want `DateLastModified`? In your question you say "correct updated date" so I guess you should be using `DateLastModified`.

Comment: I want the `DateCreated`. But it returns one which is not correct. For example, the file was created in the morning but the script returns a date from last week.

Comment: So the file did not exist at all last week?

Comment: It does exist, but is overwritten each week.